# Excel: Pick multiple values based on minimum

Tags: excel

I have a table with all various values.
These values are summed on a single row.
I have another column into which I would like to put a third value based on the minimum value of the summed items.
At the moment I am using

```
=IF(MIN(C20:F20)=C20,C1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=D20,D1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=E20,E1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=F20,F1))))
```

But my problem with above is if there are two minimum values that are equal it will just pick the first.
For example if the lowest value is 0 shared by Columns C and E then C will be selected when I want to display all columns who match the requirement MIN.
Any thoughts on how I could add achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it seems, that you like the "IF"-statement, i have a nice solution for you:

```
=IF(AND(C20=D20;D20=E20);CONCATENATE(C1;D1;E1);IF(OR(C20=D20;D20=E20;C20=E20);IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=C20;MIN(C20:F20)=D20);CONCATENATE(C1;D1);IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=D20;MIN(C20:F20)=E20);CONCATENATE(D1;E1);IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=C20;MIN(C20:F20)=E20);CONCATENATE(C1;E1);IF(MIN(C20:F20)=C20;C1;IF(MIN(C20:F20)=D20;D1;IF(MIN(C20:F20)=E20;E1;IF(MIN(C20:F20)=F20;F1)))))));))
```

*BUT: take a look at the semicolons and commas (in my excel version i need to seperate the arguments with ";", i think you have to seperate them with ","); so your solution should be:*

```
=IF(AND(C20=D20,D20=E20),CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1),IF(OR(C20=D20,D20=E20,C20=E20),IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=C20,MIN(C20:F20)=D20),CONCATENATE(C1,D1),IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=D20,MIN(C20:F20)=E20),CONCATENATE(D1,E1),IF(AND(MIN(C20:F20)=C20,MIN(C20:F20)=E20),CONCATENATE(C1,E1),IF(MIN(C20:F20)=C20,C1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=D20,D1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=E20,E1,IF(MIN(C20:F20)=F20,F1))))))),))
```

what is going on with this beautiful formula :) :

well, `AND(C20=D20,D20=E20)` checks if all fields have the same value:
if that is true, the headers of your column (C1,E1 and D1) , get concartenated as String!!!
if that is false, the same process starts to look up, if 2 values are the same ->
if that is false, your the formula you posted is processed;

hope it helped you:)

Comment: Helped alot, I was kind of trying to avoid this as this matches 2 out of the 4. In theory the 4 could match and then I would like all those to be displayed but that turns the formula into one hell of a long piece of work - but thanks, i appreciate the help

Comment: I think its the only way, your piece works but misses column F, i think i should be able to clean it up to se whats wrong though. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess really what im looking for is a way to use "where"

Comment: yes, you should look up "HLOOKUP / VLOOKUP" perhaps this could help you!